# WP7 WebBrowser Control's NavigateToString is not displaying images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on the WebBrowser control in WP7.1 Mango.
This is the sample HTML I wrote and asked the webBrowser to navigate To String.

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
           // Constructor
            public MainPage()
            {
                  InitializeComponent();

                  webBrowser1.Loaded += webBrowser1_Loaded;
            }

           void webBrowser1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
                var html =
                   "<html><body>hi there" +
                   "<img src =\"http://alansmoneyblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/google-logo.jpg\"/>" +
                   "</body></html>";

                   webBrowser1.NavigateToString(html);
           }
    }
```

But, only text is being loaded and images are not being loaded. Am I missing some thing here?

**UPDATE:**
I updated the code and still the image is not coming.

Comment: Perhaps your device is not 'connected'. You can probably verify that by opening the browser on your device and see if you can view that page.

Comment: I even tried on my device. It is not working even on it. After seeing all the comments I am getting a feeling that I should reinstall the sdk.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are some problems with [proxy settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754351%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). But this wasted a lot of my time.

Answer (score 4):

This code is actualy working, it showed hi there for me, and a small google logo. The thing you may miss is that you have to copy this in the webbrowsers Loaded event.

Comment: I updated the code and still it is not loading the image. Will there be any other settings for that.?

Comment: this is how it is coming. dyp.im/68mcwdkEza4

Comment: maybe try it like this: var html =
    @"<!doctype html><html><body>hi there" +
    "<img src =\"http://alansmoneyblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/google-logo.jpg\"/>" +
    "</body></html>";

Answer (score 3):

I have tried your code and it works fine for me: http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/files3/95490/ArtLH8ZO9Ff.png.

**Update:**

Here's the code of my class, just like yours:

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        browser1.Loaded += Browser1Loaded;
    }

    private void Browser1Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string html = "<html><body>hi there" +
                            "<img src =\"http://alansmoneyblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/google-logo.jpg\"/>" +
                            "</body></html>";

        browser1.NavigateToString(html);
    }
}
```

And this is the XAML-code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser1" Width="400" Height="270" />
</Grid>
```

The code is not the problem, maybe it is a problem with your internet connection. Because the text is shown but the image, which comes from the internet, is not being displayed. Check your connection and see if that's causing the problem! ;)

Comment: http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/photo/view/95500/zRygGKuS see this. Shall I send it in text format?

Comment: No not necessary! :) I saw your code and used it exactly the same in my sample but this works: http://dyp.im/mB61itCs2Yy. This is really weird!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7412/discussion-between-prakash-and-abbas)